# react native No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectStateInternal.hasCompleted() is applicable for argument types:() values:[]

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

i need some help about react native (android part)
when i try to build with ./gradlew assembleRelease
i get this error 2 errors
the first one is :

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/chocolat/Desktop/IE2P/mip-react-native/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle' line: 105

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectStateInternal.hasCompleted() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

the second one is :

```
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

can someone help already got this kind of error ?
i tried all think i found on internet (stackoverflow etc..) but nothing work for me

react native version : 0.64.2
Please

this is my build.gradle in android repo

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute().text.trim(), "../android"))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute().text.trim(), "../dist"))

        }

        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```